# Python Dictionary Update is Updating every Dictionary in a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries that I am updating through a for loop. However, it seems calling update() on a dictionary within the list is resulting in every dictionary in the list being update with the most current loop's values.

While the original code is more complex, I stripped away all the unrelated stuff. Below is a test snippet I wrote just to see if it's the issue of the other pieces in my code or just the update().

```
test = [{}] * 3

for i in range(0, 3):
        test[i].update({'test': i, 'val': i+1})
print(test)
```

The expected result is:

```
[{'test': 0, 'val': 1}, {'test': 1, 'val': 2}, {'test': 2, 'val': 3}]
```

But instead I get:

```
[{'test': 2, 'val': 3}, {'test': 2, 'val': 3}, {'test': 2, 'val': 3}]
```

Not entirely sure why this is the case. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: `[{}] * 3` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `test = [{}] * 3` creates a list of three references to the same dictionary. You're looking for `[{} for _ in range(3)]`.

Comment: The duplicate is about list of lists, but applies all the same to a list of dicts created in this way.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the quick responses. That does fix the issue. Thank you all.

Comment: To be clear, it applies to **anything**. For any `<expression>`, `[<expression>]*n` creates a `list` with `n` references to whatever object the `<expression>` evaluates to.